In triangle $ABC$, given that $\angle A: \angle B: \angle C= 4:1:2$, prove that $\frac{1}{BC}+\frac{1}{AB}=\frac{1}{AC}$.
In triangle $ABC$, given that $\angle A: \angle B: \angle C=4:1:2$, prove that $\frac{1}{BC}+\frac{1}{AB}=\frac{1}{AC}$.
This is an assigned homework question after my Ptolemy Theory’s class.
I’m able to solve this question using the Ptolemy Theorem, and I write it in the answer below.
My question is there any way to solve this question without related to a circle, maybe trigonometry method or other things.
I definitely can calculate the number of degrees for all the angles: $\angle A=\frac{720}{7}$, $\angle B=\frac{180}{7}$, $\angle C=\frac{360}{7}$.
And I found the number of degrees is quite complicated and not useful.
Edit: Don’t know why is this question closed, what details should I add? But, I would want to say that this question has no typo error. The equation is definitely correct. By sine rules, you will found $BC>AB>AC,$ so $\frac{1}{BC}<\frac{1}{AB}<\frac{1}{AC}.$

It should be $\dfrac{1}{AB}+\dfrac{1}{AC}=\dfrac{1}{BC}$

Same question here with 1) first solution by embedding your triangle into a heptagon. 2) The second one the same as yours (by Ptolemy theorem).

@user1556492: Are you sure you meant $\frac{1}{BC}+\frac{1}{AB}=\frac{1}{AC}$ and not what Euclid said?  Because I tried it your way and couldn't get the trig to work out.

related question with regular heptagon, Ptolemy's theorem, etc., with possible complex-number solution

Hints:

Law of sines:
$$BC=2R\sin\angle A,\\ CA=2R\sin\angle B,\\AB=2R\sin\angle C$$
where $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle.

$$\sin u +\sin v=2\sin(\tfrac{u+v}2)\cos(\tfrac{u-v}2).$$

If $7x=\pi$, then $\sin4x=\sin 3x$.



Here is a solution that uses triangle similarity.
Extend $[CB$ to point $D$ such that $|AB|=|BD|$. By identifying the angles at each vertex, we notice the similarity $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DAC$ (both have angles $4x,2x,x$ if you will).
Next, we notice $|AD|=|AB|+|AC|$. To see this, mark a point $E$ on $[AD]$ such that $|DE|=|DB| \ \ (=|AB|)$ and observe that $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle ABE$, and therefore $|AD| = |AE| + |ED| = |AC| + |AB|$.
To finally obtain the desired relation, $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DAC$ implies $$\frac{|AB|}{|BC|} = \frac{|DA|}{|AC|}$$ using which we get
$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|AB|} + \frac{1}{|AC|} &= \frac{|AB|+|AC|}{|AB|\cdot|AC|} \\
&= \frac{|AD|}{|AD|\cdot|BC|} \qquad \text{by   } |AD|=|AC|+|AB| \text{   and   } |AB|\cdot|AC|=|AD|\cdot|BC| \\
&= \frac{1}{|BC|}
\end{align}$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

Let the angle for $\angle A=4x, \angle B=x, \angle C=2x$.



Construct the circumcircle for triangle ABC.
Let D be a point on the circumcircle such that $AC=CD$, connect $AD, BD, CD$
$\angle CAD= \angle ADC= \angle ABC=x$
$\angle BCD= \angle BAD= 4x-x=3x$
$\angle CBD= \angle CAD=x$
$\angle ABD= \angle ADB= 2x \implies AB=AD$
$\angle BCD=\angle BDC= 3x \implies BD=BC$
By using Ptolemy Theorem,
$$AB \times CD+ AC \times BD= AD \times BC$$
$$AB \times AC + AC \times BC= AB \times BC$$
$$\frac{1}{BC}
+\frac{1}{AB}=\frac{1}{AC}$$.

You asked the question and answered it at the same time. Why is so? If you already know the answer, why ask that?

@M.Riyan It is explained in the text.
